# SQL Nested Case Statements Within Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I'm having problems getting back the data I'd expect from a stored procedure. The procedure is used to both insert and update record, and this determines which parameters are set when called. My example here is assuming the DATE type parameter has the default value of NULL, i.e. they have not been passed into the sp. I have broken the code down into a small section to fix, rather than include the entire procedure code, as follows:

```
-- these would be sp parameters
declare @CustomerId int = 15
declare @Indicator varchar(5) = 'Yes'
declare @ProjectTypeId tinyint = 1
declare @FutureEffectiveDate as date = null

        SELECT
            CASE @FutureEffectiveDate
                WHEN NULL THEN                      
                    CASE @Indicator
                        WHEN 'Yes' THEN 
                            -- can only be 1, 2 or 3 to return relevant date
                            CASE @ProjectTypeId 
                                WHEN 1 THEN DI.[NextFormalEffectiveDate]
                                WHEN 2 THEN DI.[NextInterimEffectiveDate]
                                WHEN 3 THEN DI.[NextAccountingEffectiveDate]                            
                            END
                        -- data should be NULL if @Indicator not 'Yes'
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                ELSE @FutureEffectiveDate
            END AS [FutureEffectiveDate]
        FROM 
            [_Staging].[DataImport_2] AS DI
        JOIN 
            [CustomerView] AS CV ON CV.[CustomerNumber] = DI.[BillingInvoiced]
        JOIN 
            [ProjectType] AS PT ON PT.[ProjectType] = DI.[ProjectType]
        WHERE 
            CV.[CustomerID] = @CustomerId AND
            PT.[ProjectTypeID] = @ProjectTypeId
```

So the idea is that, for records where a field contains the text 'Yes', and based on the project type for that record, it selects one of three dates. If the field is not 'Yes' then it should return NULL, ignoring the project type. If the date parameter is NOT null, then it should simply return the parameter passed in. The result is returned as the column 'FutureEffectiveDate'. With the example data I have, I would expect a date to be returned as the relevant field is 'Yes', and the column NextFormalEffectiveDate has a value (as project type is 1).
 Oddly enough, if you exclude the outer CASE statement, it works. So the issue is around determining what to do based on the DATE parameter, but i cannot see why the outer CASE statement is breaking the result.

Comment: Do you know you are passing in NULL as your date parameter? I have often this passed as empty string and people thought it would be NULL when in fact it is 1900-01-01.

Comment: Yes, the intention here is that the sp can be used by both my UI and the data import process, so rather than write two procs, I default the parameters to null in the signature, so if they are not passed in, the sp can read them from the database and perform the UPDATE, but if populated they will be used as part of the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you checked `@FutureEffectiveDate` for `NULL` in CASE statement is wrong. Here is a small demo

```
declare @FutureEffectiveDate as date = null

Select Case @FutureEffectiveDate when NULL then 1 else 0 end
```

The above query will result `0`. Because the above `CASE` statement validates the input expression like `@FutureEffectiveDate = NULL` which will fail. `NULL` should be compared using `IS` operator

Here is the correct way to compare `NULL`

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN @FutureEffectiveDate IS NULL THEN
           CASE ..
```

Comment: I'd tried CASE @FutureEffectiveDate WHEN IS NULL but had gotten a syntax error, and first time I looked at your demo, couldn't see the difference, but having the argument within the WHEN, as you say, does indeed resolve the issue. Is this format only necessary when comparing with NULL? In the other CASE statements I have used the format CASE Argument WHEN X THEN...END and these work as expected.